# Error in custom provider, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: playframework-2.0, jclouds

I am writing a play 2.0 application using jcloud.

This is the first time I am using "play dist" to run my application.

Everything is working well when I use "play run" or "play start" and even "play stage" but when I run "play dist" and then "dist/start" I get the error pasted below (had to remove some lines because it is too big).

This is the code I am running - it simply configures the jcloud interface.

```
 public void init(){
        String cloudProvider = conf.server.bootstrap.cloudProvider;
        String username = conf.server.bootstrap.username;
        String apiKey = conf.server.bootstrap.apiKey;
        logger.info( "initializing bootstrapper with [cloudProvider, username, apiKey]=[{},{},{}]", new Object[]{cloudProvider, username, apiKey} );
        ContextBuilder contextBuilder = ContextBuilder.newBuilder( cloudProvider );
        contextBuilder.credentials( username, apiKey );
        ComputeServiceContext context = contextBuilder.buildView( ComputeServiceContext.class );
        _compute = context.getComputeService();
        _nova = context.unwrap();
    }
```

How do I resolve it?

```
3203) Error in custom provider, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@6c27ca12
  at org.jclouds.http.handlers.RedirectionRetryHandler.class(RedirectionRetryHandler.java:49)
  while locating org.jclouds.http.handlers.RedirectionRetryHandler
    for parameter 1 at org.jclouds.http.handlers.DelegatingRetryHandler.<init>(DelegatingRetryHandler.java:59)
  at org.jclouds.http.handlers.DelegatingRetryHandler.class(DelegatingRetryHandler.java:59)
  while locating org.jclouds.http.handlers.DelegatingRetryHandler
    for parameter 3 at org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.<init>(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.java:101)
  at org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.class(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.java:80)
  while locating org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService
  at org.jclouds.http.config.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorServiceModule.configure(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorServiceModule.java:42)
  while locating org.jclouds.http.HttpCommandExecutorService
    for parameter 0 at org.jclouds.http.TransformingHttpCommandExecutorServiceImpl.<init>(TransformingHttpCommandExecutorServiceImpl.java:44)
  while locating org.jclouds.http.TransformingHttpCommandExecutorServiceImpl
  at org.jclouds.http.config.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorServiceModule.configure(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorServiceModule.java:43)
  while locating org.jclouds.http.TransformingHttpCommandExecutorService
    for field at org.jclouds.rest.config.RestModule$Factory.executorService(RestModule.java:199)
  while locating org.jclouds.rest.config.RestModule$Factory
  at org.jclouds.rest.config.RestModule.configure(RestModule.java:102)
  while locating org.jclouds.rest.internal.AsyncRestClientProxy$Factory
    for parameter 1 at org.jclouds.rest.config.RestModule$CreateAsyncClientForCaller.<init>(RestModule.java:168)
  while locating org.jclouds.rest.config.RestModule$CreateAsyncClientForCaller
  at org.jclouds.rest.config.RestModule.provideAsyncDelegateMap(RestModule.java:160)
  at org.jclouds.rest.config.RestModule.provideAsyncDelegateMap(RestModule.java:160)
  while locating com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache<org.jclouds.internal.ClassMethodArgs, java.lang.Object> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=async)
    for parameter 4 at org.jclouds.rest.internal.AsyncRestClientProxy.<init>(AsyncRestClientProxy.java:116)
  at org.jclouds.rest.internal.AsyncRestClientProxy.class(AsyncRestClientProxy.java:93)
  while locating org.jclouds.rest.internal.AsyncRestClientProxy<org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.NovaAsyncApi>
  at org.jclouds.rest.config.BinderUtils.bindAsyncClient(BinderUtils.java:94)
  while locating org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.NovaAsyncApi
  at org.jclouds.rest.config.BinderUtils.bindClient(BinderUtils.java:88)
  while locating org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.NovaApi
    for parameter 0 at org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.compute.loaders.LoadFloatingIpsForInstance.<init>(LoadFloatingIpsForInstance.java:46)
  at org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.compute.loaders.LoadFloatingIpsForInstance.class(LoadFloatingIpsForInstance.java:41)
  while locating org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.compute.loaders.LoadFloatingIpsForInstance
  while locating com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader<org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.zonescoped.ZoneAndId, java.lang.Iterable<? extends org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.FloatingIP>> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=FLOATINGIP)
  at org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.compute.config.NovaComputeServiceContextModule.instanceToFloatingIps(NovaComputeServiceContextModule.java:168)
  at org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.compute.config.NovaComputeServiceContextModule.instanceToFloatingIps(NovaComputeServiceContextModule.java:168)
  while locating com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache<org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.zonescoped.ZoneAndId, java.lang.Iterable<? extends org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.FloatingIP>> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=FLOATINGIP)
    for parameter 1 at org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.compute.functions.RemoveFloatingIpFromNodeAndDeallocate.<init>(RemoveFloatingIpFromNodeAndDeallocate.java:54)
  while locating org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.compute.functions.RemoveFloatingIpFromNodeAndDeallocate
    for parameter 2 at org.jclouds.hpcloud.compute.HPCloudComputeServiceAdapter.<init>(HPCloudComputeServiceAdapter.java:29)
  while locating org.jclouds.hpcloud.compute.HPCloudComputeServiceAdapter
  while locating org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.compute.NovaComputeServiceAdapter
  while locating org.jclouds.compute.ComputeServiceAdapter<org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.zonescoped.ServerInZone, org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.zonescoped.FlavorInZone, org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.zonescoped.ImageInZone, org.jclouds.domain.Location>
  at org.jclouds.compute.config.ComputeServiceAdapterContextModule.provideHardware(ComputeServiceAdapterContextModule.java:105)
  at org.jclouds.compute.config.ComputeServiceAdapterContextModule.provideHardware(ComputeServiceAdapterContextModule.java:105)
  while locating com.google.common.base.Supplier<java.util.Set<? extends org.jclouds.compute.domain.Hardware>>
  at org.jclouds.compute.config.BaseComputeServiceContextModule.supplySizeCache(BaseComputeServiceContextModule.java:290)
  at org.jclouds.compute.config.BaseComputeServiceContextModule.supplySizeCache(BaseComputeServiceContextModule.java:290)
  while locating com.google.common.base.Supplier<java.util.Set<? extends org.jclouds.compute.domain.Hardware>> annotated with @org.jclouds.collect.Memoized()
    for parameter 3 at org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.compute.functions.ServerInZoneToNodeMetadata.<init>(ServerInZoneToNodeMetadata.java:83)
  while locating org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.compute.functions.ServerInZoneToNodeMetadata
  while locating com.google.common.base.Function<org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.zonescoped.ServerInZone, org.jclouds.compute.domain.NodeMetadata>
    for parameter 3 at org.jclouds.compute.strategy.impl.AdaptingComputeServiceStrategies.<init>(AdaptingComputeServiceStrategies.java:83)
  at org.jclouds.compute.strategy.impl.AdaptingComputeServiceStrategies.class(AdaptingComputeServiceStrategies.java:65)
  while locating org.jclouds.compute.strategy.impl.AdaptingComputeServiceStrategies<org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.zonescoped.ServerInZone, org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.zonescoped.FlavorInZone, org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.domain.zonescoped.ImageInZone, org.jclouds.domain.Location>
  at org.jclouds.compute.config.ComputeServiceAdapterContextModule.defineAddNodeWithTagStrategy(ComputeServiceAdapterContextModule.java:166)
  at org.jclouds.compute.config.ComputeServiceAdapterContextModule.defineAddNodeWithTagStrategy(ComputeServiceAdapterContextModule.java:166)
  while locating org.jclouds.compute.strategy.CreateNodeWithGroupEncodedIntoName
    for parameter 0 at org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.compute.strategy.ApplyNovaTemplateOptionsCreateNodesWithGroupEncodedIntoNameThenAddToSet.<init>(ApplyNovaTemplateOptionsCreateNodesWithGroupEncodedIntoNameThenAddToSet.java:83)
  at org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.compute.strategy.ApplyNovaTemplateOptionsCreateNodesWithGroupEncodedIntoNameThenAddToSet.class(ApplyNovaTemplateOptionsCreateNodesWithGroupEncodedIntoNameThenAddToSet.java:64)
  while locating org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.compute.strategy.ApplyNovaTemplateOptionsCreateNodesWithGroupEncodedIntoNameThenAddToSet
  while locating org.jclouds.compute.strategy.impl.CreateNodesWithGroupEncodedIntoNameThenAddToSet
  while locating org.jclouds.compute.strategy.CreateNodesInGroupThenAddToSet
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@6c27ca12
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor26.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:85)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
        at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:98)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
        at org.jclouds.rest.AsyncClientFactory.create(AsyncClientFactory.java:48)
        at org.jclouds.rest.config.AsyncClientProvider.get(AsyncClientProvider.java:47)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
        at org.jclouds.rest.config.ClientProvider.get(ClientProvider.java:64)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
        at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:98)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
        at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:98)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
        at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:98)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
        at com.google.inject.spi.ProviderLookup$1.get(ProviderLookup.java:89)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:98)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:737)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:204)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:198)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:198)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:179)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:109)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
        at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildInjector(ContextBuilder.java:321)
        at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildInjector(ContextBuilder.java:261)
        at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildView(ContextBuilder.java:521)
        at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildView(ContextBuilder.java:501)
        at beans.ServerBootstrapperImpl.init(ServerBootstrapperImpl.java:123)
```

My dependencies are

```
  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "13.0.1"  ,
  "org.jclouds" % "jclouds-allcompute" % "1.5.1"  ,
  "org.reflections" % "reflections" % "0.9.8"  ,
  "org.jclouds.driver" % "jclouds-sshj" % "1.5.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

in the past, there was a class conflict with reflections.  shotgun answer, but does this help? https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/blob/master/play-compute/project/Build.scala

Comment: I should have added my dependencies to the question. I updated the question. Class conflict sounds like a reasonable cause but I have no idea how to get rid of it.